# multiple users Image processing .net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, image

I have a background image on which I write text using 2d namespace in .net MVC
and save and serve it to my users.

I was thinking on how to improve my application performance.
I want to avoid the IO reads every time I load the background image. 
Can I load the background image to an application-wide shared memory?

Does it make any sense? if so, can someone please post a code sample?